# Visual Studio does not have the template G1ANT.Robot Addon

Tags: g1ant

The Visual Studio does not have the G1ANT.Robot Addon Template. How to install the G1ANT SDK in the Visual Studio? What should I do? and which type of Visual Studio I had to download? Community or Enterprise or Professional?? Now I have downloaded the Community! Did any one get the G1ANT.Robot Addon Template??

Comment: [Apparently](https://manual.g1ant.com/getting-started/installation.md) you have to register ...

Comment: "Community" is a free version, the others you need to buy. See [comparison chart](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/compare/)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the community version and it should work just fine.

Use thik link to download the SDK: [https://github.com/G1ANT-Robot/G1ANT.Sdk/raw/master/G1ANT.Sdk.vsix][1]

You can try ending the process if the installation gets stuck but the sdk will be installed anyways.

Hope this helps!